# How to proof this equation given a substitution?

Tags: integration, proof-verification

I need to proof that $$\int_{0}^{\pi}xf(\sin(x))dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin(x))dx$$ The problem says that the substitution $u=\pi-x$ is useful. Following their advice $u=\pi-x,du=-dx$ $$-\int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi-u)f(\sin(\pi-u))du$$ What do I do next, this the first time I encounter integrals writeen like this and I am not that familiar with proof thanks in advance !

Comment: You were told to substitute $x=\pi-u$ ,  not $x=\pi-4$.

Comment: Also, the new integration limits are wrong.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align*}
I&=\int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi-u)f(\sin(\pi-u))du\\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi-u)f(\sin u)du\\
&=\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin u)du-\int_{0}^{\pi}uf(\sin u)du\\
&=\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin u)du-I.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}xf(\sin(x))dx=$$
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi-x)f(\sin(\pi-x))dx=$$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi-x)f(\sin x)dx=$$
$$\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin x)du-\int_{0}^{\pi}xf(\sin x)dx \implies $$
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}xf(\sin(x))dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin(x))dx$$